# Emulator: Error: texture file unsupported version or corrupted

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I am new to the Android Programming and I was working on tutorials from web. I could use emulator before but on last days even a simple "hello world" app is not working. Event log shows this error as: "Emulator: Error: texture file unsupported version or corrupted." Then it finishes the project with exit code 3. I searched this error but I couldn't find anything. Does anyone know something about this error?

Answer (score 1):

Create new emulated device and it should work on that.

For me that error occur after emulator update, but after creating new one everything start working again as before.